# Grey area below grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with grouped style. I have set the footer height to 0.

```
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.0
```

When I scroll down all the way I get a grey area at the bottom of the table view.

[image]

How do I get rid of this area?

Edit: This problem only happens for grouped table style. If I use plain style I don't get the blank area. But using a plain style is not an option for other reasons.

Comment: I'm seeing this in a grouped tableview, also. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be the height of section footer which is consuming this area. Try setting the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat.min
}
```

Comment: This simply made the area white. But the blank area is still there.

Comment: Yes returning CGFloat.min fixed the problem. It is interesting that returning 0 does not work. Nor setting sectionFooterHeight to 0 or CGFloat.min.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the tablefooter view with a UIView eg:

```
`tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`
```

Comment: This did not get rid of the area.

Comment: you are using grouped tableview or plain..?

Comment: As my question says I am using grouped style. The problem only happens when I use grouped style.