# Huge empty area at end of table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There seems to be a huge empty, opaque area below my cells. As I scroll the table view up, I can see there's an opaque area that covers the bright orange background of the table view as shown in the right screen shot. Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055968/grey-area-below-grouped-uitableview), I tried setting the footerHeight to 0 and footerView to an empty view, but it didn't work. Any solution?

[image]
[image]

**Code**

```
private func setupSongsTable() {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Screen.width, height: Screen.height)
        songsTable = UITableView(frame: frame, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
        songsTable.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        songsTable.backgroundColor = .orange
        songsTable.isOpaque = false
        songsTable.backgroundView = nil
        self.view.addSubview(songsTable!)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
}
```

Comment: @cloudcal do you know another solution to fix my problem?

Comment: Check if your View has any background color set. Make it light orange similar to your tableview.

Comment: @BilawalBaig I set `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green` and it doesn't show up on the screen b/c the table view is probably covering the view

Comment: Why are you setting songsTable's opaque to false? Set `songsTable.isOpaque = true` and see what happens.

Comment: And why are you doing this `songsTable.backgroundView = nil`? Remove this line. Setting backgroundView to nil won't help.

Comment: @BilawalBaig It was based on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127933/swift-3-how-to-remove-the-grey-areas-of-the-screenshot-of-uitableview). Okay, I set it to opaque & removed the `songsTable.backgroundView = nil`, but nothing happened

Comment: Why are you not adding UITableView from Storyboard? It makes many issues to be solved easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was creating more than 4 sections, so the extra space represented empty sections. The correct code is below.

```
public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let numOfLetterSections = Array(songsDictionary.keys).count
    return numOfLetterSections + 1 //4 sections
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `tableView.backgroundColor` to `.clear`. If that doesn't work, check to see what your cell's background colors are. `cell.backgroundColor`. Judging from your screenshots, it looks like your cells have a white background color while your table's are the default apple light grey color.

Comment: I just updated my answer. There's an opaque section just below the cells. I'm not sure why

Comment: instead of frame setting your table, use AutoLayout. After you add your table to your view, repeat this for the left, top, bottom, and right constraints.

    `addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: table, .left, .equal, view, .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))`

^ do that for all four sides.